# Expanding sheet rows and appending information of another sheet in accordance with a common column

Tags: excel, append, vba

I am trying to unify the information present in two different sheets by expanding the number of rows of the first one in accordance with a column present in both sheets (`project name`).

Suppose my data are in the following form.

- **Sheet1**: in the column `project name` I have a number of *non-repeating* projects names. I also have a `info` column with project-specific information. The last column, `research question`, is empty.
- **Sheet2**: I again have a column called `project name`, but now *each project name can repeat more than once* in accordance to the number of research questions which characterize it (`research question` column).

Here you have a sample of my data:

**sheet1:**

```
    project name     info    research question
-------------------------------------------------
      name_1        bla_1          
      name_2        bla_2          
      name_3        bla_3
```

**sheet2:**

```
    project name     research question
------------------------------------
        name_1        rq_1a
        name_1        rq_1b
        name_1        rq_1c
        name_2        rq_2a
        name_3        rq_3a
        name_3        rq_3b
```

What I would like to do is to unify the information present in the two sheets by appropriately expanding *sheet1* rows and appending *sheet2* rows, that is:

**Resulting sheet:**

```
    project name    info    research question
--------------------------------------------
       name_1      bla_1          
       name_1                  rq_1a
       name_1                  rq_1b
       name_1                  rq_1c
       name_2      bla_2          
       name_2                  rq_2a
       name_3      bla_3          
       name_3                  rq_3a
       name_3                  rq_3b
```

The fact is that I have hundreds of projects and thoudands of research questions.. how would you implement something like this?

Thank you very much,

Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can accept something ***CLOSE*** but not exact to your expected out put you could do something like this (this is basically Alex Weinstein's answer)

On Sheet 2 Insert a Column Between project name and Research Question, And label if Info:

[image]

Then add the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A3,A4)>0,"",VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet1!$A$3:$B$10,2))
```

and this will result in the following:

[image]

Now If you need your Exact output you can use the following Sub:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
Dim Sh2 As Worksheet
Dim rngProjectName As Range
Dim rngSh1ProjectNames As Range
Dim lngInsertRow As Long

Set Sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

Set rngSh1ProjectNames = Sh1.Range("A4", Sh1.Range("A" & Sh1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each rngProjectName In rngSh1ProjectNames
    On Error Resume Next
    lngInsertRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(rngProjectName.Value, Sh2.Range("A1", Sh2.Range("A" & Sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), 0)
    rngProjectName.EntireRow.Copy

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Sh2.Rows(Sh2.Range("A" & Sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Else
        Sh2.Rows(lngInsertRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next rngProjectName
End Sub
```

as a note I added an error for when the Project Name on Sheet 1 doesn't exist on sheet2 it adds it to the end, IF you will NEVER have a Project Name on Sheet1 that IS NOT on Sheet2 then you can replace:

```
On Error Resume Next
    lngInsertRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(rngProjectName.Value, Sh2.Range("A1",Sh2.Range("A" & Sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), 0)
    rngProjectName.EntireRow.Copy

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Sh2.Rows(Sh2.Range("A" & Sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Else
        Sh2.Rows(lngInsertRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
```

With simply:

```
        lngInsertRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(rngProjectName.Value, Sh2.Range("A1",Sh2.Range("A" & Sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), 0)
        rngProjectName.EntireRow.Copy
        Sh2.Rows(lngInsertRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Or if you would like different behavior then you can just do what you'd like.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! This is an impressive answer, especially in terms of clarity of the coding. Bests, Stefano

Answer (score -2):

You don't need VBA for this. You just need the VLOOKUP function. That function will let you get the values from the second table that match the current row's name.

Introduction to VLOOKUP: https://www.google.com/search?q=vlookup+intro&oq=vlookup+intro&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: That is appropriate only when there is 1 matching row in sheet2 for each row in sheet2.

Comment: so is it basically going the other way around? (starting from sheet2 information instead of starting from sheet1?)

Comment: This will not add an extra row of information into the sheet though. In the original question Sheet2 goes form having 4 rows of `name_1` to having 5, where it inserts a row from Sheet1